# Resonance in a series parallel combination circuit

Tags: parallel, series, resonance, lcr

This lc circuit has capacitors in parallel and series with the inductor. What happens at resonance? Will it be parallel resonance, series resonance or can you have multiple resonances? Is the total capacitance simply the sum of all 3 capacitors [image: LC Parallel Series]

Comment: C1 is across V1 so it does nothing, because V1 is already a short circuit to AC. Is V1 supposed to be a signal source with internal impedance?

Comment: V1 is pulsed DC

Comment: More information about V1 is needed.

Comment: you can define resonance when the imaginary part of the equivalent impedance of the whole circuit becomes 0 so you can do the series of C2 C3 L1 and then the parallel with C1 and find when it becomes 0, this will depend on w, so you need to define a frequency w if you do it by fourier S if you do it by laplace, which will be decided by  V1 even if it is a DC pulse you need the height and the pulse width....

Comment: Have you simulated this circuit (anyway, by adding a little resistor serial with the voltage generator)? What is the variable of interest?